# Django admin clear button for form

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

I was wondering if there is a way to put a "Clear Form" button on the admin forms of the apps in django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your templates directory create a folder admin, in this create a file `submit_line.html`, paste this code in there (this is actually the original submit_line with the last `<input...` statement added:

```
{% load i18n %}
<div class="submit-row" {% if is_popup %}style="overflow: auto;"{% endif %}>
{% if show_save %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save' %}" class="default" name="_save" {{ onclick_attrib }}/>{% endif %}
{% if show_delete_link %}<p class="deletelink-box"><a href="delete/" class="deletelink">{% trans "Delete" %}</a></p>{% endif %}
{% if show_save_as_new %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save as new' %}" name="_saveasnew" {{ onclick_attrib }}/>{%endif%}
{% if show_save_and_add_another %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save and add another' %}" name="_addanother" {{ onclick_attrib }} />{% endif %}
{% if show_save_and_continue %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save and continue editing' %}" name="_continue" {{ onclick_attrib }}/>{% endif %}
<input type="reset" value="Reset form" />
</div>
```

Now, while this will do what you want, the Reset Form button will appear not to be clickable  in some browsers (some effect is disabled). It will however work. You can also replace the input by `<button type="reset">Reset form</button>` but I find this rather ugly. Finally, you could also search the stylesheets to see which code fails (it's something like a input['reset'] that's missing somewhere). But anyway, this works, have fun with it